# Can compare values from Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> with ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I created a `Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> map` and I would like to compare each value in map with one `ArrayList<String> likeList` and get key if they match. I will bring the key to use later.

I tried to run my code like this, but it doesn't work because it returns nothing:

```
for (int key : map.keySet()) {
    if(map.get(key).equals(likeList)){
        index = key;
        Log.d("IndexN", String.valueOf(index));
    }
}
```

Then, I tried this:

```
int index = 0;
for (Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if(entry.getValue().equals(likeList)){
        index = entry.getkey();
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you are trying to do. Do you want to compare each `ArrayList<String>` in your map to your one `likeList` and get the corresponding key if they match? Also, what does `it doesn't work` mean? Please specify expected and actual outputs.

Comment: It would be good if you edit your question with detailed clarity containing an example with expected output

Comment: It does not return index when I try the code above. Sorry for inconvenient, it's my first time for using stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

> It does not return index when I try the code above.

From this comment, I understood that as soon as you find a match in the map, the `index` should be recorded and further processing should be stopped. In other words, either there is only one match of `likeList` in the map or you want to find the first match of `likeList` in the map. If yes, you need to break the loop as soon as the match is found (shown below).

```
for (int key : map.keySet()) {
    if (map.get(key).equals(likeList)) {
        Log.d("IndexN", String.valueOf(index));
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that this will give you the same value, each time you execute it, only when the map has only one match of `likeList` or the map is a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). If it is a `HashMap` and it has more than one matches of `likeList`, you may get a different value each time you execute it because a `HashMap` does not guarantee the order of its entries.

However, if there can be multiple matches of `likeList` in the map and you want to log all the matches as well as get the list of the corresponding keys, you can do it as follows:

```
List<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int key : map.keySet()) {
    if (map.get(key).equals(likeList)) {
        Log.d("IndexN", String.valueOf(index));
        indexList.add(key);
    }
}

// Display the list of corresponding keys
System.out.println(indexList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a list of the key to store all match

```
List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();
for (int key : map.keySet()) {
    if (map.get(key).equals(likeList)) {
        indices.add(key);
    }
}
```